# Can we use both try with resources and multi-catch together in Java 7?

Tags: java, java-7

Hi can we use both try with resources and multi-catch together in Java 7? I tried to use it and it gives compilation error. I may be using it wrongly. Please correct me.

```
try(GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzip))
    {
         br.readLine();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes!** you can.

But, your problem is in `FileNotFoundException` with `IOException`. Because `FileNotFoundException` is subclass of `IOException`, which is invalid. Use only `IOException` in catch block. You have also missing the one right parenthesis `)` in try statement. Thats why, you got errors.

```
 try(GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzip)))
 {
    br.readLine();
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very much possible in Java SE 7. A piece from the official [Oracle Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html) :

**The new syntax allows you to declare resources that are part of the try block. What this means is that you define the resources ahead of time and the runtime automatically closes those resources (if they are not already closed) after the execution of the try block.**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
    new URL("http://www.yoursimpledate.server/").openStream())))
   {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YY");
    Date date = format.parse(line);
   } catch (ParseException | IOException exception) {
    // handle I/O problems.
   }
}
```

@Masud in right in saying the `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`, and that they cannot be used like

`catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }`

But you certainly can do something like this:

```
try{
    //call some methods that throw IOException's
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e){} 
catch (IOException e){}
```

Here's a Java tip that is very useful : **When catching exceptions, don't cast your net too wide**.

Hope it helps. :)